# multi dimensional array for perl

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I would like to push data to a multi-dimensional array in Perl

such as `quality_list[i][j]`
using:

```
  push(@quality_list, $string_list, $qp);
```

But, I think, I could not use it. Could you help me about it?

```
@se1s = ('1','5','8');
@se2s = ('3','2','4');

sub test()
{
foreach $se1(@se1s)
  {
  foreach $se2(@se2s)
    {

    push(@quality_list, $se1, $se2); 

    }
  }
}
```

I expect such as:

```
quality_list[1][0] = 1
quality_list[1][1] = 3


quality_list[2][0] = 5
quality_list[2][1] = 2
```

Comment: Provide a runable example with Input and expected output

Comment: Thanks, please see the revised version.

Comment: Your array starts at zero. What's the first row of `@quality_list` expected to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really clear what you want. But this seems to get the results that you ask for.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;

my @se1s = ('1','5','8');
my @se2s = ('3','2','4');

my @quality_list;

foreach (0 .. $#se1s) {
  push @{$quality_list[1]}, $se1s[$_];
  push @{$quality_list[2]}, $se2s[$_];
}

say Dumper \@quality_list;
```

I think that reading "[perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)" will be very useful for you.